# UNIX Shell script: process id related

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have written one shell script which kills a process based on certain condition. 
My script 'A' will call another script 'B' which identifies process id and kill it.

Before running the script I have ran

```
ps -ef | grep processA
```

This gave me result process id, say, 11111

The script B gets process id through this command

```
ps -ef|grep processA|grep -v stop|grep -v grep|awk ' { print $2 } '
```

I have added the same command in script A and got process id as 11111
However when it gets invoked in script B, the process id will be different, say, 22222.
I am not sure why even though it is same command, the process id identified are different. Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: What are the exact names of the scripts A and B? And the ps command? The difference should be in the pipelines `grep processA|grep -v stop|grep -v grep`

Comment: That they are different processes ?

Comment: Rather than the `grep -v grep`', try `grep 'process[A]'` (make sure you include the quotes).  This is a well-known grep/RE trick using the `[A]` to match a single character, but avoiding catching yourself in the `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure that it's the same command in script A as in Script B?

Second, if you are interested in the PID of processA you can do

```
pgrep processA
```

which will give you the PID of processA directly.

Third, what are you trying to achieve with the command

```
ps -ef | grep processA | grep -v stop | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

It looks like you are looking for the processA, but you only want the processes without containing the word 'stop' and 'grep'. Using pgrep, you will not get the grep process looking for processA.

If you provide more information (e.g. your scripts), we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Get the process id and kill it? Here is one other way:

```
> proc_name=$1".pid"
> pid=$(cat /var/run/$proc_name)
> kill -9 $pid
```